# Fluxgate magnetometer design for a non-electrical engineer

Tags: sensor, power-amplifier, magnetometer

I am working on a project where I have made a fluxgate sensor. The sensor consists of a drive winding and a sense winding. I have a function generator going into an amplifier (to drive the core to saturation) then through the drive winding and to the ch1 of my oscilloscope. The sense winding is directly connected to the ch2 of the oscilloscope.

This is going to be very trivial, however, I am having a difficult time searching for an answer. How do I create a circuit to obviate plugging into a power amplifier. I need to drive the core deep into saturation so the output of the function generator is not enough. Plus at some point, I would like to make this into a portable device.

Comment: "*How do I create a circuit to obviate plugging into a power amplifier.*" What are you asking? Are you asking how to build a power amplifier to plug the function generator into? Are you asking for a circuit to replace both the power amplifier and the function generator?

Comment: You just need to drive the core with a bipolar square wave current. What current level are you looking for? And what frequency or range of frequencies?

Comment: How to build a circuit to replace both. what are the components I need? What does the circuit look like? Is this a piece I can buy off the shelf or do I need to design one?             Thank you in advance, sincerely.

Comment: easy enough after you have specs for f, , V, I. Some are square wave drive and 2f detect and others are sine wave 1f detection